# $\Phi$ is consistent $\iff$ every finite subset of $\Phi$ is consistent

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am not sure if I have memorized the definition correctly but a formula $\psi$ is derivable from $\Phi$ ($\Phi\vdash\psi$) iff there is a subset $\Gamma$ such that the sequence  $\Gamma\Rightarrow\psi$ is derivable in sequent calculus.

And $\Phi\subseteq FO$ (set of sentences without free variables) is consistent iff $\Phi$ is not inconsitent and $\Phi$ is inconsistent iff every sentence without free variables $\psi$ can be derived from $\Phi$.

I have trouble to understand the $\Leftarrow$ side of the equivalence in the title.

How can I prove that if every subset of $\Phi$ is consistent then $\Phi$ is also consistent?

I could not find a proof, my attempt:

Suppose $\Phi$ is inconsistent but every subset of it is consistent. I don t see why this would yield a contradiction. Because $\Phi$ is inconsistent. I know that for every $\psi$ there is a subset $\Gamma$ such that the sequence $\Gamma\Rightarrow\psi$ can be derived from sequent calculus.

Comment: $\Phi$ is a subset of $\Phi$...

Comment: @EricWofsey I wanted to say finite thanks for pointing it out. WHile $\Phi$ may be infiite the equivalence still holds if we only look at the finite subsets

Comment: Using the contrapositive, assume $\Phi$ is inconsistent.  This means there is a proof of a contradiction from $\Phi$.  As proofs are finite in length, it can only use finitely many statements from $\Phi$.  That finite subset is then inconsistent.

Comment: thank you the question is answered

Comment: @RossMillikan can you please write that comment out as an answer? I like my favorited questions to have answers outside the comments. (They serve as good references when I forget something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the contrapositive, assume $\Phi$ is inconsistent. This means there is a proof of a contradiction from $\Phi$. As proofs are finite in length, it can only use finitely many statements from $\Phi$. That finite subset is then inconsistent.